# OSM layer does not print in GeoServer printing module

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, printing, pdf

I am new with the GeoServer printing module, in GeoServer version 2.6.0, freshly installed a few days ago.

I can now print WMS layers and I think I configured the OSM data correctly. But it still does not work for printing OSM, so I must have mistakes somewhere.

I am using OpenLayers and the default url for OSM seems to be "tile.openstreetmap.org"

I have set up the OSM url in the hosts section in the config.yaml file:

```
- !dnsMatch 
   host: tile.openstreetmap.org
```

My printing url is constructed as follows:

```
var url = 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf?spec=';

var options = { 
    units: 'm', 
    srs: 'EPSG:900913', 
    layout: 'A4 portrait', 
    dpi: '300', 
    mapTitle: 'This is the map title', 
    comment: 'This is the map comment', 
    layers: [ 
        { 
            baseURL: 'http://tile.openstreetmap.org', 
            singleTile: false, 
            type: 'OSM', 
            maxExtent: [-20037508.3392,-20037508.3392,20037508.3392,20037508.3392], 
            tileSize: [256, 256], 
            extension: 'png', 
            resolutions: [156543.0339, 78271.51695, 39135.758475, 19567.8792375, 9783.93961875, 4891.969809375, 2445.9849046875, 1222.99245234375, 611.496226171875, 305.7481130859375, 152.87405654296876, 76.43702827148438, 38.21851413574219, 19.109257067871095, 9.554628533935547, 4.777314266967774, 2.388657133483887, 1.1943285667419434, 0.5971642833709717] 
        }, 
        { 
            baseURL: 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/geoserver/abc/wms', 
            opacity: 1, 
            singleTile: true, 
            type: 'WMS', 
            layers: [layers], 
            format: 'image/jpeg' 
        } 
    ], 
    pages: [ 
        { 
            center: [center.lon, center.lat], 
            scale: map.getScale() 
        } 
    ] 
}; 

var printUrl = url + JSON.stringify(options);
```

As you can see below, the WMS layers are correctly printed, but the OSM layer does not appear, even though there was no error message during the printing.

http://we.tl/nI6y7lNNhV

Comment: GeoServer can only print layers it knows about. The Osm layer is only in the client.

Comment: @iant, I know, but apparently it is possible. Check this out: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/printing/protocol.html#osm

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answers.

I changed the base url to:

```
baseURL: 'http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/'
```

in the OSM configurations.

I also changed the host to

```
- !dnsMatch
  host: a.tile.openstreetmap.org
```

in the YAML file.

Also! I found out why it didn't work. It was a stupid mistake of mine.

I used JPEG format for the WMS layers that were over the OSM layer.

I only changed the format to PNG, to allow transparency in the WMS layers and I am now able to see the OSM layer.